# ThreeJs PCD Loader for dynamic data

Tags: html, three.js, lidar

I have been looking for ways to view LIDAR data in HTML5. I found that `ThreeJs` provide 3D visualization.
`ThreeJs` provide a way to view Point Cloud data / LIDAR Data from a file.
https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/PCDLoader

But I cannot find any example of using PDCLoader with dynamic data coming from an API or any other source other than a file.

Can anybody help here ?

Couldnt find any example or any method in TheeJs official Docs that would provide such functionality.